# Trying to encrypt entire user folder but getting access errors

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer, encryption, ntfs

In my Windows 7 Pro system, I am trying to encrypt my entire user folder but certain folders or files keep throwing up flags like this:

[image]

Now, I have granted the process of encrypting Admin rights, so what else can I do? I am reluctant to log in as another user and do this encryption because I am not sure if the encryption would be under that other user' login credentials..

Comment: You are currently logged in as the user, correct?  What are you using to encrypt the profile?

Comment: The regular windows 7 encrypt option for the folder and sub folders

Answer (score 0):

you need to find out what app / program is accessing  /AppData and  close it til its been encrypted/decrypted as the case may be ..... process or task manager are likely easiest /fastest ways to determine that if not obvious..

Comment: That is a bit cumbersome, though I suppose I could start the computer in safe mode and do this. But I mean, this problem has to have been faced by people before me and a more elegant solution was made.

Comment: Quick question:other than the encryption tool/software what user apps are running (that you started up or had on autostart)  try there first or mount it from another system for ex from another pc with target drive in an enclosure and run the tool that way since its not booted that way nothing on it would be running....this would require the other system have this tool of course